# How to delete event from device calendar in ionic by title?

Tags: angularjs, calendar, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic application. I want to delete an event from device calendar by using its `event title` ? I am aware about using `window.plugins.calendar.deleteEvent()` method, but

1. Can I use it to delete event by title only?
2. Is there any method which deletes all the events in calendar which
   has particular title?
3. What is best way to override previous event of device calendar.

Following is my code

```
        var createEventSuccess = function () {
          alert('Job added to calendar:'+job.id);
        }
        var createEventError = function (error) {
          alert('Error adding Job to calendar : ' + error);
        }

        var deleteEventSuccess = function () {
            alert('Event Deleted:'+job.id);
            window.plugins.calendar.createEventWithOptions(title, location, job.services, scheduledTime, scheduledTime, calOptions, createEventSuccess, createEventError);
        }

        var deleteEventError = function (error) {
            alert('Problem in Deleting:'+error);
        }

        var findEventSuccess = function () {
            alert('Event found');
            window.plugins.calendar.deleteEvent(title, null, null, null, null, deleteEventSuccess, deleteEventError);
        }

        var findEventError = function (error) {
            alert('Event not found : ' + error);
            window.plugins.calendar.createEventWithOptions(title, location, job.services, scheduledTime, scheduledTime, calOptions, createEventSuccess, createEventError);
        }

        window.plugins.calendar.findEvent(title, null, null, null, null, findEventSuccess, findEventError)
```

I don't want to depend on other fields cause that fields may change by title will be same so I want find or delete job only by using title.

I have searched on google but no document found relevant to my requirement.

Please help..

Thanks.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I have edited my question..

Comment: have you worked with ngCordova before? http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/calendar/ it is much more conveinient

Comment: no didn't worked with it. Is it possible to access event by title in it?

Comment: it should work... if it doesn't you did not include it properly or have some other errors in your code. I would suggest you try again. I am saying that, because with ngcordova calendar plugin it is quite easy to achive what you want.

Comment: ye that delete process is not working properly . First of all it is not deleting as per date range too .like i created 3 event in a day in like 9 am 1 pm and 8 pm .Then i want to only last one then i use start date n end date like this requirement but it is deleting all event of the same day .\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [plugin's Site](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin) it says:

```
  // delete an event (you can pass nulls for irrelevant parameters, note that on Android `notes` is ignored). The dates are mandatory and represent a date range to delete events in.
  // note that on iOS there is a bug where the timespan must not be larger than 4 years, see issue 102 for details.. call this method multiple times if need be
  // since 4.3.0 you can match events starting with a prefix title, so if your event title is 'My app - cool event' then 'My app -' will match.
  window.plugins.calendar.deleteEvent(newTitle,eventLocation,notes,startDate,endDate,success,error);
```

**The dates are mandatory and represent a date range to delete events in.**

Comment: ok... so I may have to give 1 year difference up to current date to find events in that time span..!!

Comment: was your event found when you call findEvent?

Comment: u mean without dates??

Comment: and m facing one more issue.